# Mapbox "invalid location for binary target" error during Fastlane build resolving spm dependency

Tags: mapbox, fastlane, swift-package-manager

I'm receiving this error while xcode tries to resolve Swift Package Manager dependencies with these command:

`xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace -scheme MyScheme`

```
Fetching from https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-core-maps-ios.git

invalid location for binary target 'MapboxMobileEvents' in https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-ios.gitxcodebuild: error: Could not resolve package dependencies:
  invalid location for binary target 'MapboxMobileEvents' in https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-ios.git
```

I don't understand how to fix this issue, I neither found too much on the web.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, did u find the solution to this?

Comment: yes, there was a typo in my `.netrc` configuration